# OSGi bundle always has a 'starting' status after maven build

Tags: java, maven, osgi

So I have tried adding a new bundle to my project. Everything works perfectly in Eclipse Equinox but there is a problem with the Maven (Tycho) build. My bundle is visible in OSGi console and its status is STARTING but it would't start when its service is needed. I can start the bundle manually from the OSGi console and then it works. I can even restart my app after that and it still works.

When I go into bundles.info I can see this line:

```
org.eclipse.orion.server.authentication.github,1.0.0.v20151013-0508,plugins/org.eclipse.orion.server.authentication.github_1.0.0.v20151013-0508.jar,4,false
```

If I change 'false' to 'true' at the end then it also works. How to configure my bundle to make it 'true' by default?

The larger story behind my bundle (let's call it A) is: It implements an interface defined in bundle B (so A requires B) and registers a service under this interface. This service is used inside B (B does not know about A before runtime). I heard removing this kind of cyclic dependency could help but I don't want to modify B to avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: "There is a problem with the Maven build": What do you use to start the container during the Maven build? A JUnit extension or a Maven plugin? What is the startlevel of your framework? And what is the startlevel of your bundle?

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos Maven uses Tycho and creates an Equinox artifact. The startlevel of all bundles in the project is 4. However, I don't know how to check the framework's startlevel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a real problem. It is a typical behaviour of Equinox. It shows bundles as starting until another bundle actually needs the service the bundle is offering. So typically you can just ignore the status starting in equinox.

Alternatively you can run your bundles on felix where they should be reported as Active.

Comment: You mean that Equinox uses Lazy activation policy for bundles?

Comment: Yes. You can also observe this in karaf if you switch to equinox. I was pretty puzzled when I saw that the first time :-)

Comment: That is strange. I think it is against the specification. From osgi.org: "A bundle started without the START_ACTIVATION_POLICY option will always be eagerly activated." If the bundle is in STARTING state that means that its activate method is either running or has not been called yet (due to Lazy-Activation policy). As a result, some OSGi services might not be available that can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Might be a bug in equinox then. I only saw this in the most recent equinox version till now like it is used in Karaf 4.0.0.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Everything is alright on Equinox - the status is STARTED from the beginning. The problem is it won't start automatically (even when it is needed) in the app built with Maven.

Comment: That sounds a bit strange. Maven itself can not start OSGi bundles. What do you use to start OSGi and your bundle?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider You're right. Actually Maven uses Tycho to create the Equinox artifact. I meant that it works correctly on Eclipse Equinox.